# OpenLDAP Replication problem

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a LDAP master server installed on CentOS-5.4 and I have installed LDAP on one more machine and I want it be configured as LDAP slave server but when I am importing the LDIF file or trying to create any new object in slave LDAP getting the below errors:

> LDIF text import Could not add object
>   dc=transcomus,dc=com LDAP said:   Server
>   is unwilling to perform Error
>   number:   0x35
>   (LDAP_UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM)
>   Description:  The LDAP server refused
>   to perform the operation.

There is no permission issue already checked that on /var/lib/ldap

Any help much appreciate..

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: What kind of replication have you set up / are you trying to set up?  Are you following the instructions from http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html , or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, I am using slurpd replication method. It was running fine but somehow it broke down and till then its not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're attempting to import a database dump into a running slave, either by means of `ldapadd` or `slapcat`. A running slapd instance with a replication mechanism configured in slave mode will reject all write attempts and return the message you provided.

If my slurpd based slapd servers ever became inconsistent I executed a fairly straight forward recovery procedure:

1. Put the master into read-only mode.
2. Make a fresh dump from the master and copy it to any inconsistent slaves (or copy from backups).
3. Completely stop slapd on the slave you want to recover.
4. Clear the contents of the data directory, `/var/lib/ldap` (you might want to save your `DB_CONFIG` file if the parameters aren't defined in slapd.conf)
5. Use `slapadd` to rebuild the directory on the slave (move `DB_CONFIG` back if necessary)
6. Start the slave normally.
7. Switch the master back into read-write mode.

   yes, I am using slurpd replication method. It was running fine but somehow it broke down and till then its not working

You're probably running OpenLDAP 2.3.43 since that's what's packaged in CentOS 5.4. Unfortunately because of that you're also likely to run into replication issues again in the future unless you can upgrade to a newer OpenLDAP (2.4) server.

`slurpd` was very flawed, check out [the OpenLDAP 2.4 docs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#Replacing%20Slurpd) for a complete explanation of why. The newer OpenLDAP releases come with a new replication mechanism called `syncrepl` which is much more robust and nearly impervious to failure.

In the future if you're interested in getting help migrating to a newer OpenLDAP server I can offer guidance there as well.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have already implemented the syncrepl machenism. I found it very robust and easy to configure. Syncrepl can be configured on 2.3.x versions of openldap. But in synrepl mastertomaster replication support starts with 2.4 versions. I have implemented RefreshOnly as of now, but  I have plans to implement mastertomaster in future and want to have Windows AD(LDAP) server to be used to sync with OpenLDAP... any thoughts on this.